# Wave Texture: How can I have even bands proportions and distributions?

Tags: node-editor

So I have been trying to make this semicircle with lines radiating from one point using wave texture node.

The problem is that the lines are not equally distributed and are stretched and compressed as they get closer to the x and y axes respectively, making them having uneven thickness.

[image]

I don't know though if the Normal mapping type has anything to do with these weird observations, but so far it is the only method that gives results close to what I want.

[image]

I would very much appreciate sharing another approach or a fix to this situation.

thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a gradient texture in Radial Mode.

[image]

[image]

Same idea with the wave texture:

[image]

Comment: Thank yoou so much for help...